# mysql query hierarchic

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help to find a sql query

```
CREATE TABLE album (
    id_album INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sous_album (
    id_sous_album INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    id_album INTEGER REFERENCES album(id_album)
);

CREATE TABLE photo (
    id_photo INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    id_sous_album INTEGER REFERENCES sous_album(id_sous_album)
);

INSERT INTO album(id_album, nom) VALUES
('1', 'album1'),
('2', 'album2'),
('3', 'album3')
;

INSERT INTO sous_album(id_sous_album, nom, id_album) VALUES
('1', 'sous album 1', '1'),
('2', 'sous album 2', '1'),
('3', 'sous album 3', '1'),
('4', 'sous album 4', '2'),
('5', 'sous album 5', '2'),
('6', 'sous album 6', '3')
;

INSERT INTO photo(id_photo, nom, id_sous_album) VALUES
('1', 'photo1', '1'),
('2', 'photo2', '1'),
('3', 'photo3', '1'),
('4', 'photo4', '1'),
('5', 'photo5', '2'),
('6', 'photo6', '2'),
('7', 'photo7', '3'),
('8', 'photo8', '3'),
('9', 'photo9', '3'),
('10', 'photo10', '4'),
('11', 'photo11', '5'),
('12', 'photo12', '6'),
('13', 'photo13', '6'),
('14', 'photo14', '6'),
('15', 'photo15', '6')
;

SELECT distinct  album.nom, count(photo.id_photo)
from album, photo, sous_album
where album.id_album=sous_album.id_album
AND sous_album.id_sous_album=photo.id_sous_album
group by album.nom
order by album.nom`
```

this query give me the name of the album and the number of photos but i want also the sous album and their numbers of photo... can u help me ?

the result :

```
nom    | count(photo.id_photo)
album1 | 9
album2 | 2
album3 | 4
```

i need this result :

```
nom          | count(photo.id_photo)
album1       | 9
sous album 1 | 4
sous album 2 | 2
sous album 3 | 3
album2       | 2
sous album 4 | 1
sous album 5 | 1
album3       | 4
sous album 6 | 4
```

Comment: distinct does nothing for you here. And consider using explicit JOIN syntax rather than this archiaic, implicit, comma-join syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
     , y.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT a.nom 
            , COUNT(*) total 
         FROM album a 
         JOIN sous_album ap 
           ON ap.id_album = a.id_album 
         JOIN photo p 
           ON p.id_sous_album = ap.id_sous_album
        GROUP 
           BY a.nom
     ) x
  JOIN  
     ( SELECT a.nom nom_album
            , ap.nom nom_sous_ablum
            , COUNT(*) total 
         FROM album a 
         JOIN sous_album ap 
           ON ap.id_album = a.id_album 
         JOIN photo p 
           ON p.id_sous_album = ap.id_sous_album 
        GROUP 
           BY a.nom
            , ap.nom
     ) y
    ON y.nom_album = x.nom;
```

Note that this particular query will only return an album if there is at least one sous_album (and photo) associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your solution... i find a other one...

```
SELECT a.nom, sa.nom, COUNT( * ) AS NbPhoto FROM album a INNER JOIN sous_album sa ON sa.id_album = a.id_album INNER JOIN photo p ON p.id_sous_album = sa.id_sous_album GROUP BY a.nom, sa.nom WITH ROLLUP
```